# make new objects in s3 bucket public by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket in which the objects within it need to be made public, right now anytime I upload a new file I have to click on it and then click "make public using acl" I wonder if there is a way to set it so any new file uploaded to my bucket is public by default. I tried giving the bucket itself public permission but I still have to make the individual objects public too.

Answer (score 2):

For details see the post
[How to Make All Objects in Amazon S3 Bucket Public by Default](https://www.h3xed.com/web-development/how-to-make-all-objects-in-amazon-s3-bucket-public-by-default).

To resume:

- Open the Properties for the bucket you want to make public
- Click "Permissions"
- Click "Edit bucket policy"
- Copy and paste the following text:

  ```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
          "Action": "s3:GetObject",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test.h3xed.com/*",
          "Principal": "*"
        }
      ]
    }
  ```
- Change `test.h3xed.com` to the actual name of your bucket
- Click "Save".

Note: Users must still use the exact URL to your resources.
They cannot view the "index" of your bucket or list its contents.

Comment: I get "You don't have permissions to edit bucket policy", I tried as root user and as IAM user with with full access.

Answer (score 0):

@fred, must probably your problem was solved by now. Related to your comment 'I get "You don't have permissions to edit bucket policy", I tried as root user and as IAM user with with full access.', it could be because the Block Public Access to your bucket is enabled (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/configuring-block-public-access-bucket.html). This can be set at bucket level or account level (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/configuring-block-public-access-account.html).
[Block public access bucket AWS S3 console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yuWn.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).